400 (Bad Request) when requesting OAuth2 access token to login
I am developing an application using Angular. This application needs to consume an API on Microsoft through the URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/token
This API returns a token that will be used in other requests from the application. I have already made the configurations and releases that I believed were necessary for this access, such as creating the client_id, client_secret, etc.
Given this, I have the following situations:
When I execute the request via Postman or via Node (running only a .js file for testing) the return is 200, that is, it returns the information with the token. When I execute the request through the application removing the browser security in development mode for testing (i.e. chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security) the server returns 200 also with the token information. When I run the application using normal browser access, I get a 400 (Bad Request) error.
With that, I'm not sure if I have a problem with the Angular application or a problem with the release or configuration of the client_id.
Has anyone ever had to perform this authentication? Or, do you have any idea how I could solve this problem?
I didn't find anything specifically about this URL and I followed several tips for configuring the client_id but nothing worked.
I am at your disposal if you need any further information.

do you experience simillar behavior with the session folder, but without security disable flag?
